# Could not execute build : LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to import some source code in Android Studio 3.0.1, but I'm getting the following error: `The app gradle file must have a dependency at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consume`

I don't know what the problem is, althgough I have gradle 4.9

My Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                google()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong

            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
            mavenCentral()
            google()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

The entire error report:

> Error:Internal error: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not
>   execute build using Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip'.   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$invokeGradleTasks$2(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:373)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:426)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.run(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:209)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution
>   failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.    at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)

Comment: Can you explain yourself better?

Comment: Could you please give any context?

Comment: sorry I am try cuz I  dont use to ask in this site using codes

Comment: It seems like you are missing dependancies, try adding the required dependancy in the module gradle file

Comment: how ? I have to download it from google

Comment: you are using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06` and then complain "it does not work" ...

Comment: it give me this error

Answer (score 1):

Change Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.1.4 with use gradle version 4.4-all

Top-level build file: buildscript:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```